# Which sect does Swami Mukundananda belong to?

Tags: guru, sects, gita

[Swami Mukundananda](https://youtube.com/c/Swami)  is a good Hindu scholar, translator and commentator.

He [translated the Gita](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/)  and wrote a commentary on it.

So which sect does he belong to - ISKCON, Advaita Vedanta, Dvaita Vedanta or something else?

Comment: Related [Why do some Hindu sannyāsi names end in 'ānanda' e.g., Vivekānanda, Śivānanda etc?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16948/3500)