# Does a person become Sanyasi get cut-off from his family line ? Why do they change their name?

Tags: sanyasi

When a person takes Sanyas , he usually changes his name. Why is it like this ? Does he get cut-off his family line ?

Comment: They don't change their names themselves. After Sannyasa Diksha they are given a new name by their Gurus. The name depends on the Sampradaya. After any Diksha the disciple gets a new name (its called Diksha nama signifying a new birth after Diksha) and from then on he is known by that name in his spiritual circle.

Comment: See this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24534/4732

Comment: Most sannyasins are given their new name by the sannyasin giving the initiation into sannyas. Sometimes another sannyasin will give the name. Other times no name is given and the sannyasin takes a name of their own inclination. On occasion a sadhu will take no name and people will start addressing them in a manner that becomes the name they are known by. There is no hard and fast rule.